# Is there a way to make two actions on CSS when a div is focused?

Tags: html, css

[https://imgur.com/a/ns4bYND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niaMf.png)I have 2 divs:

```
.new-task {
    width: 390px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code:focus {
    width: 390px;
}
```

When .room-code:focus is active, I also want to make new-task's width to 90px, how do I do that with only css?

```
.room-code:focus ~ .new-task  {
    width: 90px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.room-code:focus + .new-task  {
    width: 90px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

.room-code:focus-within .new-task {
    width: 90px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

tried all three but I can't do it

Comment: Please provide HTML code for your question.

Comment: The selector will change depends on where you put the `new-task` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to target a new-task that has a focused room-code successor

```css
.new-task {
    width: 390px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code:focus {
    width: 390px;
}

.new-task:has(~ .room-code:focus) {
    width: 90px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<input class="new-task" />
<input class="room-code" />
```

But if the elements are not siblings you will probably have to target it with a parent element

```css
.new-task {
    width: 390px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code {
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.room-code:focus {
    width: 390px;
}

.some-parent:has(.room-code:focus) .new-task {
    width: 90px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-parent">
  <div>
    <input class="new-task" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="room-code" />
  </div>
</div>
```